# laravel-echo-server realtime notification not working

Tags: php, node.js, redis, laravel-5.6, laravel-echo

I am new in Laravel-echo-server. I have built an web app with laravel and use laravel-echo-server to get realtime notifications and messages. It's working fine on local server. But when I uploaded it to live server it is showing on console

> GET
>   http://example.xyz:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MO25vx0
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

In my local server I command

> 'laravel-echo-server start'

to start laravel echo server.

But I don't know how to manage it on production server.
Even I am new in VPS.

Please give me some tips to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the port 6001 open on your production server?

Comment: It's works now. That was a configuration problem.